# Get/List all Windows event log events in the last n minutes in powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, event-log

After I encounter an error or issue, I'd like to quickly review events for the last several minutes to see if there is any helpful information. The trouble is, I don't know which particular log might have the events I'm looking for so I want to just show ALL of them. I want to use powershell because opening event viewer and creating a filter takes too long and the faster I can copy and paste a command into powershell, the fewer events I'll have to sift through. I don't want to have to note the exact time the event would have taken place, just a relative time.

I know how to get events from a *single* Windows event log for the last n minutes, for example `Get-EventLog -LogName System -After (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-10) | Format-Table -AutoSize -Wrap`, but as the [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-eventlog?view=powershell-5.1#parameters) says:

> -LogName
> Specifies the name of one event log. To find the log names use Get-EventLog -List. **Wildcard characters are not permitted.** This parameter is required.

So my thought is that I could iterate through all log names, running `EventLog` on each of them and concatenating the results.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a quick command which will iterate each log and show all events which occurred in the last ten minutes sorted by the time they occurred:

```
Get-EventLog -List `
| %{Get-EventLog -LogName $_.Log -After (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-10) -ErrorAction Ignore} `
| Sort-Object TimeGenerated | Format-Table -AutoSize -Wrap
```

Or the same thing in one line:

```
Get-EventLog -List | %{Get-EventLog -LogName $_.Log -After (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-10) -ErrorAction Ignore} | Sort-Object TimeGenerated | Format-Table -AutoSize -Wrap
```

> `Get-EventLog` uses a Win32 API that is deprecated. The results may not be accurate. Use the Get-WinEvent cmdlet instead.

### Get-WinEvent:

Recommended approach - it works with Microsoft PowerShell and Windows Powershell (>=v6) and using a FilterHashtable is a lot faster than the approach above.

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{LogName='*';StartTime=(Get-Date).AddMinutes(-10)} | Sort-Object TimeCreated
```